# Getting 404 while accessing the api

Tags: node.js, api, express, apache2

I am setting up the node js project to access the api.

directory tree view

```
└── html
    └── perb
        ├── bin
        ├── models
        ├── node_modules
```

project tree view

[image]

But end up getting the 404. 
But when I am trying to access through localhost, it is working fine.

**localhost address :** localhost:3000/trainer/logintrainer

**server address:** ip_address/perb/trainer/logintrainer

in bin/www file listen port is 3000

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

but I have tried to change it to 80 and 8080 also but nothing helps.

I am using the apache2 server and setup as ( https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/application/misc/set-up-a-nodejs-app-for-a-website-with-apache-on-ubuntu-1604/ )

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check your server logs. Make sure you're actually hitting your application, as you're probably not. Apache httpd needs to know how to redirect to your Node application's port. You may want to look at using a tool like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) to do this for you. That's an add-on for Apache `httpd` which handles the port mapping and process management.

Comment: when i check pm2 logs, it is not hitting the server. @tadman

Comment: When you say you're hitting it at "ip_address" do you mean 127.0.0.1 or something else? If it's 192. something, you're probably reading another tutorial that assumes you have another proxy set up which you don't

Comment: I mean regular ip like 34. something.. @Asthmatic

Comment: The `httpd` configuration is often based on host name, so if you're using the `<VirtualHost>` directive, which is standard, that host name needs to match to route things to the proper site.

Comment: can you show some example @tadman

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the Passenger approach, it will pay long term dividends. Their documentation is very complete, and there's also a ton of other examples that cover that exact thing.

Comment: ok @tadman i have installed it. Do i need to change anything else?

Comment: If it can auto-detect your app and you have a good Virtual Host configuration then it should work. If not you need to check a bunch of things, so it's hard to say what precisely might be wrong. Try and find a good reference for that Passenger + Apache httpd + Node.js application deployment.

Comment: Can you check this link @tadman https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363154/invalid-command-passengerapproot

Answer (score 1):

In the files you set up in your tutorial, can you set your proxy to point at the ip you're trying to hit instead of localhost

```
<Location /nodejs>
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8080
</Location>
```

Comment: So do i need to change 127.0.0.1:8080 to regular IP address i.e .34. something ?

Comment: yes it doesn't know to listen at the ip you're trying to hit it on because you never told it to listen there

Comment: actually I was not to find the example.com.conf but there was two file under the folder sites-available i.e. 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf so I have made changes in 000-default.conf