# Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot'

Tags: node.js, apache2, passenger

I am getting the error
Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

while setting up the passenger for [Node js project on AWS server.](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/walkthroughs/deploy/nodejs/aws/apache/oss/xenial/deploy_app.html#deploying-a-node.js-app-on-an-aws-production-server-with-passenger-in-apache-mode-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-(with-apt))

```
sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
What would you like to validate?
Use <space> to select.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

 ‣ ⬢  Passenger itself
   ⬡  Apache

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓

Everything looks good. :-)

What would you like to validate?
Use <space> to select.
If the menu doesn't display correctly, press '!'

   ⬢  Passenger itself
 ‣ ⬡  Apache

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓

Everything looks good. :-)
```

perb.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ip_address

    # Tell Apache and Passenger where your app's code directory is
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/perb/public
    PassengerAppRoot /var/www/html/perb/

    # Tell Passenger that your app is a Node.js app
    PassengerAppType node
    PassengerStartupFile app.js

    # Relax Apache security settings
    <Directory /var/www/html/perb/public/>
      Allow from all
      Options -MultiViews
      #Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
      #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you need to select the "Apache" option to compile the extension (module) the server needs.

Comment: I am not able to understand. Can you tell in bit details. @tadman

Comment: Run `passenger-config validate-install --validate-apache2 --auto`